# azure app service with a spring boot : waiting for response to warmup

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure, azure-web-app-service

I deploy a spring boot application on azure (app service), but it takes many time to get started (20 minutes sometimes),  I always have in the logs this line with many occurences :

```
Waiting for response to warmup request for container myapp_id_on_azure_0_917c0e77. Elapsed time = 326.0884541 sec
```

I seems to wait something to effectively start the application ... but what ?
Anyone have tips ?

FYI : I execute : **java -jar /home/site/wwwroot/my_app.jar** for starting my application. I not define any server port in application.properties on my spring boot application. I also verify that on "**general settings**" of the app service the option "**always on**" is enabled ...

Answer (score 0):

> FYI : I execute : java -jar /home/site/wwwroot/my_app.jar

***From this sentence, I can probably guess that you are using the linux platform.***

I think your question is meaningless, in the absence of any log. So there should be no one who can give you a direct and effective solution, but can only provide you with troubleshooting ideas.

**Troubleshooting steps**

1. If you use windows platform, you should add `web.config` under `wwwroot` folder.

   Instead of executing `java -jar /home/site/wwwroot/my_app.jar` in the command line.
2. If you use linux paltform, and your webapp use `myapp.jar` file , so you should use `Java SE`, like below.

   [image]
3. Whatever paltform you use, you shold check application log, find error message, it will help you solve the issues.

Comment: Hello Jason,
Yes I use Linux and and have Java SE configured like on your screenshoot. I not have any errors logs, just the line I mentioned ...

Comment: @kylebb It's really a pity, because under normal circumstances there will be no problems like yours, especially now that you can't see more logs, it is really difficult to help you on the forum.

Comment: @kylebb Let MSFT help you query logs and analyze errors.

Comment: I tried to solution this since two weeks, but cannot find any clear documentation. I change default port of spring boot and add configuration variable WEBSITES_PORT to use port 80. But same issue